cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
I found this issue already present here, I did recheck and I have added std flags. But still I can't figure out the issue.
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
  --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-df3be1d6828443a1/94606ca/substrate/primitives/runtime-interface/src/impls.rs:45:1
   |
45 | assert_eq_size!(usize, u32);
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: `usize` (64 bits)
   = note: target type: `u32` (32 bits)
   = note: this error originates in the macro `assert_eq_size` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
  --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-df3be1d6828443a1/94606ca/substrate/primitives/runtime-interface/src/impls.rs:47:1
   |
47 | assert_eq_size!(*const u8, u32);
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: `*const u8` (64 bits)
   = note: target type: `u32` (32 bits)
   = note: this error originates in the macro `assert_eq_size` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

   Compiling pallet-nfts v22.0.0 (https://github.com/moondance-labs/polkadot-sdk?branch=tanssi-polkadot-v1.11.0#94606cad)
   Compiling dp-chain-state-snapshot v0.1.0 (https://github.com/moondance-labs/dancekit?branch=tanssi-polkadot-v1.11.0#d18c151b)
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0512`.
error: could not compile `sp-runtime-interface` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air Xcavate_tanssi % 

Could someone please help me on figuring out. github_link
